# How is the word SNOB considered by English speaking people?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am not a native English speaker. I am looking for an answer to this question to be sure to use the correct sense of this word *snob*.

Actually this word *snob* will be part of my new company's name and I would love to call it "POSH & SNOB". It's a designed product shop.

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you? What aspect of the meaning is unclear?

Comment: the meaning is clear, and the same as in French. The way I want to use the word snob is in a subversive way that works in French. What the dictionary doesn't tell me is if this word is considered as a really bad word close to an insult or not, is this word used often or old fashion.

Comment: @Cedric Your question would be much improved if you included the comment in the question. Please edit your question.

Comment: It _might_ perversely be taken as a reverse-connotation usage (people seem not to mind being labelled 'wicked' in some contexts nowadays). Judging by the names some companies adopt, you can get away with most things. But it _would_ be a risk; the fact that nobody seems to have chosen the name already is instructive. (Do check that you're not purloining a name that's already been registered.)

Answer (score 3):

I am a native speaker of British English, and I think this is a fair question due to the fact that a dictionary could never fully explain the extensive social and cultural connotations of a term like this.

My main point would be that 'snob' is never a positive description of someone - so it is highly unlikely that it would be a suitable term for marketing a business.

One of the more subtle aspects of this term is that it is not exclusively used of people who are very overtly wealthy (and arrogant with it). It can refer to someone who consciously tries to give the impression of being wealthy and/or relatively well educated and who talks about others as if they were inferior - so as to create the impression that they are somehow different, and superior, to their peer-group. This type of person is characterized by being critical of others, even to the point of being dismissive, on the basis of their own superiority complex. They may imagine they have friends and acquaintances in high and influential places, or they may have a small number of such contacts and imagine this elevates them to a position above their social peers.

In reality such people tend to be deeply insecure at a personal level and often make themselves the object of ridicule - and one of the ways this is most clearly expressed is that they are referred to as 'snobs'. I therefore find it difficult to imagine anyone wanting to be associated with a shop that labels them as a 'snob' (or 'snobbish', which is the adjective that would go with 'posh').

Comment: Thank you for your answer it confirms my doubts, it helps me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. You might possibly consider 'Posh & Pampered' as a more positive combination. Pampered: Indulge with every attention, comfort, and kindness; spoil.
‘famous people just love being pampered’   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pamper

Comment: Of course, there are also people who will self define themselves as a particular *type* of snob... Someone might say, for example, 'Well, I'm a bit of a wine-snob'. How to interpret this is tricky to me, as I've never claimed to be a wine-snob, book-snob, grammar-snob or any other kind of snob. I think it is meant to be an *apparent* self deprecation, whilst really being a boast.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a swear word if that's what you're asking, but it's plainly a pejorative word - which is fine if you want to negatively comment on someone. However, I doubt you want to do that to your customers or clients by using this word in the name of your business.

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted to know thank you for your helpfull answer

Answer (score 0):

It's generally meant a negative - someone who is overly fussy or believes themselves or their opinions/taste to be superior to others. However, depending on your target market, it could still work in a slightly humourous sense.   (Kind of like the range of books, "The Idiot's Guide to...")

Although I wouldn't know enough about marketing (and I'm sure it's well outside the purview of this site) to know if it's a good idea to do use it humourously in this way or not.

Comment: Good marketing? Certainly not!

Comment: to use is it in a subversive way was the intention and works in French, but taking your comments in consideration I will definitively not use that word.